# The variable 'MyException' is declared but never used in the instance

Tags: c#, .net, exception, frameworks, ambiguity

I need to clear this warning :

```
try
 {
    // doSomething();
 }
 catch (AmbiguousMatchException MyException)
 {
    // doSomethingElse();
 }
```

The compiler is telling me : The variable 'My Exception' is declared but never used

How can I fix this.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this one,

```
try
{
    doSomething()
}
catch (AmbiguousMatchException)
{
    doSomethingElse()
}
```

Answer (score 2):

If you are not going to use the exception details, you can use the try like this:

```
try
{
    doSomething();
}
catch // all types of exceptions will caught here
// if you need to deal with particular type of exceptions then specify them like
//  catch (AmbiguousMatchException)
{
    doSomethingElse();
}
```

Or else you have to use the variable for something like the following:

```
try
{
    doSomething();
}
catch (AmbiguousMatchException MyException)
{
    WriteToLog(MyException.ToString());
  //  doSomethingElse();
}
```

where `WriteToLog` method will be defined as like the following:

```
public static void WriteToLog(string exceptionDetails) { 
  // write the details to a file/DB
}
```